# Using return values of scalar functions to calculate new results

Tags: sql-server

For a time calulation table I wrote two scalar functions to retrieve return values.

```
USE [SECI]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[sfCIKorr]    Script Date: 31.03.2014 14:14:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[sfCIKorr] 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @dteCheckInTime datetime, 
    @dtePlanTimeCheckIn datetime

)

RETURNS datetime
as
 BEGIN
Declare @dteCIKorr datetime

    --CheckInTime correction
    If @dteCheckInTime > 0 And @dtePlanTimeCheckIn > 0
        Begin
        set @dteCIKorr = @dtePlanTimeCheckIn
        end
    else If @dteCheckInTime < @dtePlanTimeCheckIn
        begin
        set @dteCIKorr = @dtePlanTimeCheckIn
        end       
    Else If (@dteCheckInTime > @dtePlanTimeCheckIn) And (@dteCheckInTime < DateAdd(minute, 15, @dtePlanTimeCheckIn))
        begin
        set  @dteCIKorr = @dtePlanTimeCheckIn
        end
    Else If @dteCheckInTime > DateAdd(minute, 15, @dtePlanTimeCheckIn)
        begin
        set  @dteCIKorr = dbo.sfRoundToHourParts(@dteCheckInTime, 4)
        End
    Else If @dteCheckInTime > 0 And @dtePlanTimeCheckIn = 0
        begin
        set @dteCIKorr = dbo.sfRoundToHourParts(@dteCheckInTime, 4)
        end
    Else If @dteCheckInTime = 0
        begin
        set @dteCIKorr = 0
        End

    return @dteCIKorr
end
```

Second one:
dbo.sfRoundToHourParts(coalesce(CheckOutTime,''), 4) which rounds up or down to a quarter hour.

Both works fine, but now I want to to use the results in an Update-query to retrieve another result which should be like this:

From VBA-Code:

```
If dteCheckInTime > 0 And dteCheckOutTime > 0 Then
        dteCalculatedTime = Format(DateDiff("n", dteCIKorr, dteCOKorr) / 1440, "hh:nn")
    Else
        dteCalculatedTime = 0
    End If
```

So as the final result I would like to do like this:

```
Update mytable
set CheckInTimeCorr= dbo.sfCIKorr(@dteCheckInTime, @dtePlanTimeCheckIn),
CheckOutTimeCorr=dbo.sfRoundToHourParts(coalesce(CheckOutTime,''), 4),
CalculatedTime=  see my VBA-Code!
Select from mytable
```

So I need the both functiuons the retrieve results which I would need to do a calculating on the further step.
By the way, I don't know, if the use of two scalar function is realy neccesary to get my query done or I could do this in an inline table function better.

Thanks your help.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

If the CalculatedTime column always depends on values in CheckInTimeCorr and CheckOutTimeCorr, I'd create it as a computed column (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CalculatedTime AS (--your code here--)
```

I wanted to help you with the actual definition of the column, but can't read VBA :(